# Can one person have multiple games with another person?

Tags: facebook

My apologies if this is a dumb question, but I can't seem to find a direct answer either way.  I am developing a game and I'd like to know if it's possible to have two people playing two different games within my app?  For instance, I could start a game with 5 of my friends that are family members, and I could also start a game with 4 of my coworkers (one of which is also one of my 5 family members).  Can I have 2 games going with the same person?  Most of the apps I know (Words with Friends, Draw Something) seem to only let you play 1 game per person, and you can't start a new game with someone until the current game ends.

Hopefully I provided enough information to get a solid answer on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most things are possible. Some are just more complicated than others. You would have to save both game states instead of just the most recent game state and then provide an interface for the user to choose which game to restart.

Comment: So there is nothing prohibiting this, it's just a matter of programming it?

Comment: Exactly, and it would make your program a lot more complex. I would code the program first for playing one person and then add this functionality later.

Comment: Thanks Nathan - appreciate the quick help!

Comment: Good luck with your coding :)